# CommCenter (from CoreTelephony.framework) is eating 600+ MB of my RAM, why do I even need it?

Tags: memory, launchd, daemons

I do not have a MacBook laptop running OS X 10.11.3.
As far as I understand, CoreTelephony.framework is about cellular networks, so it might be useful on phones, for example. But the laptop obviously doesn't have any relevant hardware.

I see CommCenter (parent process: `launchd (1)`) in Activity Monitor and it's said to consume 600+ MB of RAM. That's too much for something useless.

How can I get rid of it? And why does it show up there? (Can it be a sign of some malware and stuff?)

Update:
After killing that process manually, I don't see anything bad happening.

Comment: Just a thought but this is also used for VOIP connections, have you installed Skype or other similar VOIP service?

Comment: @SteveChambers Not Skype™, but I have installed Hangouts™ plugin for Firefox. But I am not sure if it's really used for VoIP connections, where did you got that information?

Comment: I googled CoreTelephony.framework.

Comment: Could also be Cisco WebEx / Spark (gross). I'm having the same issue, except it's eating 250% of my CPU, and seems to happen during / after calls on those services, but I'm not certain.  I'm on OSX.14.  Honestly, I just force kill the process with activity monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I *believe* this has to do with Messages/FaceTime when sending or receiving calls or text messages from associated phone numbers over the internet. I can see this process making network requests to Verizon servers, which supports this theory, as my phone number is Verizon's.